# Heroku blocking frequent incoming HTTP Put

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am currently using the free version of heroku. I have a cedar stack and I am sending up HTTP put request every 2 minutes from a client app to my web app. This will work for about the first few(1-6) request but then heroku blocks my incoming request. I've been looking all over the heroku support and I do not see anything about blocking HTTP put request. The only information I've found is that HTTP request have to be under 200 characters. I was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem. If so, how did you allow your web app to receive frequent HTTP request?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it's Heroku that's blocking your request?

Comment: I dont know of anything else could be blocking my request. So I assume its Heroku. I'm deploying my app to AWS EB to test. If it works on EB then it has to be heroku.

Comment: It would help if you gave us some information about what request you're sending, from where, and what response you receive from the server

Comment: My immediate thought is since you're only using one Heroku Dyno, this frequent request may tie it up, causing the error

Comment: Ya pretty much I moved up to two Heroku dynos and its working great now.

Comment: So I moved my updates to every 6.5 minutes and they were working great after updating to two Dynos. But I shorted the time down to 2 minutes again and it beginning to block my request. so pretty much 30 http put request per hour is too much for two dynos? I'm not sure but its pretty frustrating that heroku doesn't provide much information about put request to their webapps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. I had a bug in my client code which was using up all my sockets.